# ios swift do not center image

Tags: ios, swift, image, imageview

I have an imageView that contains an image via storyboard.

My problem is that the image seems to be centered, resulting in white space around the image, within the image view.  I would like to have the image stretched to occupy the entire imageView.  I have tried all the values for the content/view mode and none work.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Note that I can stretch the image manually in storyboard.  But, then it does not show correctly when the device is rotated, despite having set layout constraints.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of problem are you facing. Is it when rotating the device?

Comment: Are you using stretchable image? then you need to calculate margin properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the imageView's content mode

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
```

This will stretch the image to the imageView ignoring the image's original aspect ratio. If you want to keep the image's aspect ratio you might want to check `AspectFit` and `AspectFill`

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

If the image goes over the frame of the imageView you can set `ClipsToBounds` to true

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the imageView's content mode and clips to bounds simultaneously

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```